# C++ QT Logger object

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create a globally accessible object (but I am not sure if creating a global object is a good solution) which will log to file my output stream. I would like it to work similar to std::cout, but with the difference that it would log to file.

```
class Logger
{
    QFile* file;
    QTextStream* stream;

public:
    Logger(QString filePath);
    {
        file = new QFile(filePath);
        if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)
            stream = new QTextStream(file);
    }
    QTextStream* Log()
    {
        return stream;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QString filePath="Logs.txt";
    Logger l(filePath);
    MyProgram a(argc, argv);
    return a.exec();
}
```

In case it would be global, all I would have to do is `l.Log()<<"text I want to log in"`.
I would prefer it to work like `Log() << "text I want to log in"`, but any solution would be useful! :)

I want to also mention that I have came into a `logger` solution on web already, but it includes creating a temporary object - in my case constantly opening and closing file each time I want to log some text is not a solution. (unless this object would use some globally open file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [Singleton Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). In the entire program, you need only one object of your logger class. So you need to use Singleton Design Pattern and place it into a separate file and just included it in whatever you need the logger.

---

For using streaming like operators (shift operator `<<`), you simply need to overload it:

```cpp
friend Logger& operator<<(Logger& other, QString const& message)
{
        (*other.stream) << message;
        return other;
}
```

---

But in the case of Logger, it's not that simple you written. A logger base requirement are:

1. Efficiently, to be fast enough in high rate logging.
2. Thread safe, to could be used in multi-threaded programs.
3. Formatting, to be used easily.
4. Log leveling, to could categorize logs.

Take a look at: `qDebug()`, `qInfo()`, `qWarning()` and `qFatal()`. My suggestion for logging libraries are:

1. Boost.Log
2. Speed Log

Comment: Thanks, that's what I have been looking for. There is just one thing I would like to reduce, as in QT all I have to do is just write qDebug() << "string", in case of this singleton I have to call Logger::getInstance() << "string", is there a way to shorten it?

Comment: Your welcome. You could define a macro for it. `qDebug()`, `qInfo()` ... are just macro expanded to `QMessageLogger`.